# Redux updating state with null before actual data

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, express, redux, axios

I am dispatching an action that is supposed to take an input from the user and store it in a database. However, when I inspect my posts state in redux after the action is dispatched, there is a null value appended to the state array before the actual post. This is preventing me from working with the actual data in the posts array. Basically I'm wondering how to prevent null from being appended each time I dispatch a new post. Here are the relevant code [image]snippets and images.

Post Reducer:

```
import { enableAllPlugins, produce } from 'immer';

enableAllPlugins();

const initialState = {
  posts: [],
  loading: false,
  error: false,
  uploading: false,
};

const postReducer = produce((draftstate, action = {}) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'UPLOAD_START':
      draftstate.loading = true;
      draftstate.error = false;
    case 'UPLOAD_SUCCESS':
      draftstate.posts.push(action.data);
      draftstate.uploading = false;
      draftstate.error = false;
    case 'UPLOAD_FAIL':
      draftstate.uploading = false;
      draftstate.error = true;
    default:
      return draftstate;
  }
}, initialState);

export default postReducer;
```

Upload Post action:

```
export const uploadPost = (data) => async (dispatch) => {
  dispatch({ type: 'UPLOAD_START' });
  try {
    const newPost = await UploadApi.uploadPost(data);
    console.log('new post before', newPost);
    dispatch({ type: 'UPLOAD_SUCCESS', data: newPost.data });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    dispatch({ type: 'UPLOAD_FAIL' });
  }
};
```

Share Post code:

```
import React, { useState, useRef } from "react";
import ProfileImage from "../../img/profileImg.jpg";
import "./PostShare.css";
import { UilScenery } from "@iconscout/react-unicons";
import { UilPlayCircle } from "@iconscout/react-unicons";
import { UilLocationPoint } from "@iconscout/react-unicons";
import { UilSchedule } from "@iconscout/react-unicons";
import { UilTimes } from "@iconscout/react-unicons";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { uploadImage, uploadPost } from "../../actions/uploadAction";


const PostShare = () => {
  const loading = useSelector((state) => state.postReducer.uploading);
  const [image, setImage] = useState(null);
  const imageRef = useRef();
  const desc = useRef();
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const { user } = useSelector((state) => state.authReducer.authData);

  // handle Image Change
  const onImageChange = (event) => {
    if (event.target.files && event.target.files[0]) {
      let img = event.target.files[0];
      setImage(img);
    }
  };

  const reset = () => {
    setImage(null);
    desc.current.value = "";
  };

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const newPost = {
      userId: user._id,
      desc: desc.current.value,
    };

    if (image) {
      const data = new FormData();
      const filename = Date.now() + image.name;
      data.append("name", filename);
      data.append("file", image);
      newPost.image = filename;

      console.log(newPost);

      try {
        dispatch(uploadImage(data));
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    }

    dispatch(uploadPost(newPost));
    reset();
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="PostShare">
        <img src={ProfileImage} alt="" />
        <div>
          <input
            ref={desc}
            required
            type="text"
            placeholder="What's happening"
          />
          <div className="postOptions">
            <div
              className="option"
              style={{ color: "var(--photo)" }}
              onClick={() => imageRef.current.click()}
            >
              <UilScenery />
              Photo
            </div>

            <div className="option" style={{ color: "var(--video" }}>
              <UilPlayCircle />
              Video
            </div>

            <div className="option" style={{ color: "var(--location)" }}>
              <UilLocationPoint />
              Location
            </div>

            <div className="option" style={{ color: "var(--shedule)" }}>
              <UilSchedule />
              Schedule
            </div>

            <button
              className="button ps-button"
              onClick={handleSubmit}
              disabled={loading}
            >
              {loading ? "Uploading..." : "Share"}
            </button>
            <div style={{ display: "none" }}>
              <input
                type="file"
                name="myImage"
                ref={imageRef}
                onChange={onImageChange}
              />
            </div>
          </div>
          {image && (
            <div className="previewImage">
              <UilTimes onClick={() => setImage(null)} />
              <img src={URL.createObjectURL(image)} alt="" />
            </div>
          )}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default PostShare;
```

I would be glad to provide any other details if that helps.

**Update with other portions of code:**

Dispatcher of RETRIEVING_SUCCESS:

```
import * as PostApi from '../api/PostRequest';

export const getTimelinePosts = (id) => async (dispatch) => {
  dispatch({ type: 'RETRIEVING_START' });

  try {
    const { data } = await PostApi.getTimelinePosts(id);
    dispatch({ type: 'RETRIEVING_SUCCESS', data: data });
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch({ type: 'RETRIEVING_FAIL' });
    console.log(error);
  }
};
```

getTimelinePosts usage:

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import './Posts.css';
import { PostsData } from '../../Data/PostsData';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { getTimelinePosts } from '../../actions/postAction';
import Post from '../Post/Post';

const Posts = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const { user } = useSelector((state) => state.authReducer.authData);
  let { posts, loading } = useSelector((state) => state.postReducer);

  console.log('posts content', posts);

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getTimelinePosts(user._id));
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="Posts">
      {/* {posts.map((post, id) => {
        return <Post data={post} id={id}></Post>;
      })} */}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Posts;
```

Comment: since `data` is coming straight from the API, you should check the documentation if the response allows `null` values or ways to filter it. If not, a quick `data.filter(d => d !== null)` should do the trick in the reducer.

Comment: @JosephD. Yeah that works! I still find it kinda weird how null values are appended to the array before the data itself haha. Thanks for your help though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I found a solution to the null entries in my posts array. Although I'm not sure why that works, it only appends actual posts to the posts array and no null entried. All I had to do was change the way my reducer updated the state. I was using immer initially, but not anymore. Here is the code:

```
const postReducer = (
  state = { posts: [], loading: false, error: false, uploading: false },
  action
) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'UPLOAD_START':
      return { ...state, uploading: true, error: false };
    case 'UPLOAD_SUCCESS':
      return {
        ...state,
        posts: [action.data, ...state.posts],
        uploading: false,
        error: false,
      };
    case 'UPLOAD_FAIL':
      return { ...state, uploading: false, error: true };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

in postReducer, let's remove the default on the **switch** statement, we don't need it on reducer because other actions will come here and the code make all states return the initial state.

Comment: I did that but that didn't help fix the issue